# Substantivierte adverbiale Genitive, wie z.B. des Öfteren

Tags: etymology, adverb

**Welche substantivierten adverbialen Genitive neben *des Öfteren* finden Verwendung in der heutigen Sprache?**
Ich kenne nur *des Weiteren* und *des Späteren* (Letzteres fand ich bei Zweig in seinem Buch "Sternstunden der Menschheit").

**Und was ist über deren Herkunft bekannt?** Laut  [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+%C3%96fteren%2Cdes+%C3%B6fteren&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdes%20%C3%96fteren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdes%20%C3%B6fteren%3B%2Cc0)  existieren sie, anders als von mir angenommen, seit den 1860er Jahren.

EDIT: Laut [Band 4 des Dudens, Die Grammatik: Unentbehrlich für richtiges Deutsch](https://books.google.bg/books?id=ry6tCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA582&lpg=PA582&dq=des%20%C3%B6fteren%20adverb&source=bl&ots=yHVRHd6rgz&sig=v4uQN1rdYY6ZXYXEmHzI-2bejFs&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjozYXKm-jcAhUPyKYKHT1ZANYQ6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=des%20%C3%B6fteren%20adverb&f=false) nennt man dieses Phänomen **substantivierter adverbialer Genitiv**, und es wird das Beispiel vom Adverb "nah" angeführt, was den Schluss zulässt, dass die Konstruktion theoretisch für jedes Adverb möglich ist, nur dass es so gut wie keine Verwendung findet, außer für "öfter".

Comment: The word »öfter« (its positive form is *»oft«*) is not an adjective. It is an adverb. You can check this by trying to use it as attribute: *»der rote Zug«* is ok, but *»der ofte Zug«* is not. Adverbs can not be used as attributes. But *»oft«* is one of the rare exceptions of adverbs that are gradable, and it is the only one German adverb with a regular graduation (oft - öfter - am öftesten). There are just four other gradable German adverbs, all of them irregular (**sehr** - mehr - am meisten; **gern** - lieber - am liebsten; **bald** - eher - am ehesten; **wohl** - besser - am besten).

Comment: Ich finde die Frage falsch gestellt. Alle Adjektive und Adverbien *können* so verwendet werden (grammatisch-technisch gesehen). In der Praxis werden jedoch nur wenige so verwendet. Je literarischer/dichterischer/altertümlicher/experimenteller ein Text ist, desto eher wird man dort Bildungen dieser Art finden. Darum würde ich Dir **aufs Dringlichste** raten, die Frage nochmals zu überdenken, und verabschiede mich **aufs Freundlichste**, will aber **des Letzteren** noch fragen, ob Du  nur **des**-Bildungen suchst (wie die Frage es **des Deutlichsten** formuliert) oder auch solche mit **aufs**.

Comment: is this like in englsh “the lesser of two evils” ?

Answer (score 2):

Die Frage ist 'enger' gemeint, als sie zunächst gestellt scheint, und zielt auf substantivierte Adverbien, die ihrerseits in einen adverbialen Genitiv verpackt sind. Die meisten Adverbien im Deutschen sind jedoch mit Adjektiven homonym, siehe '*weit*', es sind dann Adjektiv-Adverbien wohl auch gemeint?

Einige inzwischen zu Adverbien 'herabgesunkenen' Wörtern waren ursprünglich Substantive ('*flugs, nachts*'), die sind sozusagen in Gegenrichtung desubstantiviert und hier nicht gemeint.

Zur eigentlichen Fragestellung fand ich noch ein heute allerdings nicht mehr gebräuchliches '*des nächsteren*' im Sinne von 'beim nächsten Mal'. Auch ein '*letztendlichs*' gab es mal: ein Genitiv? Und wenn ich '*des Weiteren*' sagen kann, kann ich dann nicht auch '*des Ferneren*' bilden?

Adverbiale Genitive gibt es ansonsten eine ganze Menge, die alle hier aufzuführen unangebracht wäre. Eine Kostprobe, vielleicht ist ja etwas im Sinne der Fragestellung dabei:

- etwas *des Langen und (des) Breiten / des Längeren* erklären

Bei vielen dieser Formeln lässt sich fragen, ob die Zusammenschreibung mit Kleinschreibung des ursprünglich substantivierten Wortteils nicht ein orthographie-historischer Zufall ist:

- *desgleichen*
- *hierorts, mancherorts, halbwegs, schlechterdings ...*
- *anfangs, letzten Endes, letztens, nächstens?, zeitlebens ...*
- *rechter / linker Hand*
- alle Bildungen mit '-weise', in denen das '-weise' einen verblassten Genitiv darstellt: *möglicherweise, interessanterweise, sinnigerweise ...*
- möglicherweise auch alle Bildungen mit '-wärts': *vorwärts, seitwärts, heimwärts ...*
- *schnellen Schrittes, guten Mutes (früher auch 'gutes Mutes'), hurtigen Schenkels, trockenen Fußes, besten Gewissens, erhobenen Hauptes, schweren Herzens, sehenden Auges, klaren Blickes* ...
- *eines (schönen) Tages, dieser Tage, nächsten Tags, nachts, nächtens, tags(über) ...*

Einige der Genannten fand ich hier:

[Sören Stumpf: Formelhafte (Ir-)Regularitäten. Korpuslinguistische Befunde und sprachtheoretische Überlegungen, S. 174 ff.](https://www.peterlang.com/view/9783653956368/chapter9.xhtml)

Der Autor stellt Überlegungen dazu an, in welchem Umfang derartige Muster im aktuellen Deutsch noch produktiv sein können. Auch einige Anmerkungen zum Vorkommen in älteren Sprachentwicklungsstadien sowie Literaturhinweise dazu finden sich dort.

Mit einiger Sicherheit finden sich zu einzelnen dieser Muster und zu deren Vorkommen in älterer Literatur viele weitere Angaben im DWB der Gebrüder Grimm.

Comment: Besonders krass ist der Fall «des Nachts».

Comment: @mach: Ja, das wird als Analogiebildung zu anderen Temporaladverbialien erklärt. Wie sich das sprachgeschichtlich gebildet hat, würde mich auch einmal interessieren. Man sieht bei diesen vielen '-s'-Adverbien schon ein reihenbildendes Prinzip, und solche Serien können tendenziell die Vorlage für ein neues Bildungsmuster stellen.